# Is there a best practice for creating dynamic (looped) forms with React?

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm trying to make a website with dynamic forms: some fixed part that is always visible and some flexible parts that appear when a user clicks e.g. "new incident". Multiple of these should be able to be added.

I keep all my form data as JSON objects and update them using the useState hook and the spread operator when only parts of the object is changed. I use interfaces for the object structure and store them in mongoDB.

So this works well for the fixed part, but for the flexible parts it doesn't work great. Usually a flexible part in my use case means that part is rendered with a for loop. User input in a textbox inside a loop with a hook rerenders the whole looped section **and** the textbox is unfocused. I have managed to work around the unfocusing issue by creating new useState hooks in the loop and doing almost "data acrobatics" to sync the data inside the loop with the main "form object" on certain actions. But this seems very hacky and the CPU usage also doesn't look great when typing in the looped part of the form.

Is there a good solution/practice that should be implemented here? I'm looking to primarily reduce the amount of rendering: not rerendering the parts that aren't changing.